# get unique return type of template function/generic lambda

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

Is there a way to obtain the return type of a template function/generic lambda without having to specify the argument types?

```
template<class F>
struct unique_result_of {
    using type = std::result_of_t<F( *any valid parameter combination that F can be called upon* )>;
}

auto f = [](auto x, auto y, int z) -> int {};
auto g = [](double x, auto y) -> float {};

using return_type_f = typename unique_result_of<decltype(f)>::type; // should be int
using return_type_g = typename unique_result_of<decltype(g)>::type; // should be float
```

Of couse this should only work if all functions generated by the same template function name do have a unique return type.

Comment: How would you know if they had a unique return type or not? And what would you use this information for? (let's say `g` returned `float` unless both `x` and `y` were `tuple<tuple<char>>`, in which case it returns `int`?)

Comment: What if the return type depended on an explicit template parameter, or the deduction of a template argument?

Comment: Then these callables don't satisfy the constrain that the return type should not depend on argument types so I would expect a compiler error meaning "you are trying to apply unique_result_of to a callable that can return different types depending on its argument types"

Answer (score 4):

Your given example will work with the following, but there are some caveats, mentioned below

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

struct ubiq
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr operator T&() const;
};

template<size_t>
ubiq make_ubiq();

struct broken_t;

template<typename T>
static constexpr bool is_broken_v = std::is_same_v<T, broken_t>;

template<typename T, size_t I0, size_t... I>
auto call(std::index_sequence<I0, I...>)
    -> decltype(std::declval<T>()(make_ubiq<I0>(), make_ubiq<I>()...));

template<typename T>
auto call(std::index_sequence<>) -> decltype(std::declval<T>()());

template<typename T, size_t... I>
auto call(std::index_sequence<I...>) -> broken_t;

template<typename T, size_t N>
using call_t = decltype(call<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template<typename Void, typename...>
struct collapse
{
    using type = broken_t;  
};

template<typename T>
struct collapse<std::enable_if_t<!is_broken_v<T>>, T>
{
    using type = T;  
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct collapse<std::enable_if_t<!is_broken_v<T>>, T, broken_t, Ts...> :
    collapse<void, T, Ts...> {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct collapse<void, broken_t, Ts...> :
    collapse<void, Ts...> {};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct collapse<std::enable_if_t<!is_broken_v<T>>, T, T, Ts...> :
    collapse<void, T, Ts...> {};

template<typename... Ts>
using collapse_t = typename collapse<void, Ts...>::type;

template<typename, typename>
struct unique_call;

template<typename T, size_t... Ns>
struct unique_call<T, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>
{
    using type = collapse_t<call_t<T, Ns>...>;
};

template<typename T, size_t N = 10>
using unique_call_t = typename unique_call<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
```

The following asserts passes

```
auto f = [](auto x, auto y, int z) -> int {return 42;};
auto g = [](double x, auto y) -> float {return 4.2;};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, unique_call_t<decltype(f)>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<float, unique_call_t<decltype(g)>>);
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e2f789d4b0ad3ef)

The way this works is by "scanning" a type and seeing if any number of arguments can be used to call it. The upper limit of arguments has to be pre-specified, but realistically if someone gives me something with more than ten parameters, I'm just gonna pretend that it doesn't exist anyways :D

The set of possible return types are then checked, if there are different types in there, or if there is none, the resulting type will be `broken_t`.

```
struct S
{
    int operator()(int);
    float operator()(float);
};
struct U {};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<broken_t, unique_call_t<S>>);  // passes
static_assert(std::is_same_v<broken_t, unique_call_t<U>>);  // passes
```

#### Caveats

This method cannot differentiate non-existent `operator()` and one that is overloaded for the same argument count. The following type will be perceived as only having `int operator()()`.

```
struct S
{
    int operator()();
    int operator()(int);
    float operator()(float);
};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, unique_call_t<S>>);  // passes!??
```

I have yet to think of a method that *can* do this.

Another problem is with templates

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>>* = nullptr>
int operator()(T);
```

Since we cheated and created the type `ubiq` and used that as a placeholder for arguments, it won't play nice with templates, `T` won't be an integral in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Indeed the main restriction is that it can't be used with template functions, even if they are wrapped in a generic lambda. This seems to be a dead end. As for the first caveat, it seems very minor: don't expect good results when asking for meaningless operations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, **there is no way of doing this at the moment**, as there is no way of asking the compiler what the developer put after `->` in a *trailing return type*. Maybe *reflection* could make this possible in the future.

Your best bet is either specifying the argument types or using a type that's implicitly convertible to anything else to simulate an invocation of the lambda:

```
struct any_type
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr operator T() { return *this; }
};
```

This is not perfect as it doesn't work if the lambda's body tries to invoke a method that `any_type` doesn't "mock".